# Purple screen on boot

Tags: 11.10, boot

I've downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and tried to dualboot it with Windows 7, installation proccess went forward without problems, GRUB2 recognized my win 7 boot loader and everything looked fine! I wanted to boot into my fresh Ubuntu install but before the splash screen appeared a sold purple screen was shown with no text.

I waited about 10 mins but to no avail, then I restarted and it happened again, I went into kernel editing in GRUB and deleted thoese 2 words `quiet` and another one which I forgot! I replaced it with `vesa` and some other stuff but again it didn't work, I tried WUBI and this happened again.

The only way to run Ubuntu on my machine is inside a Virtual Machine which doesn't work as a solution for me because I don't want to test Ubuntu, i want to use it! Some say it's a problem with my GPU. My GPU is a Radeon HD 6950.

Comment: A purple screen on boot isn't exactly a problem :/. Maybe try a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding 'nomodeset' to grub boot?

Answer (score 1):

You should boot with `nomodeset` on your first start-up. Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting will bring you into the grub menu. Press **e** to edit kernel parameters and remove `quiet splash` from one of the lines and insert `nomodeset` in it's place.

If it boots you should install your graphics-card driver through the **Additional Drivers** application. After this is done it should boot properly the next time you start it.