# Encrypted Ubuntu installation won't boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, encryption

I just did a fresh install of 14.04 LTS, choosing the encrypted option.  Everything seemed to go fine, and at the end it told me it needed to reboot to complete the installation.  When I clicked OK, it went to a black screen and stayed there.  I tried powering off and powering on, and just got a plain purple screen, no opportunity to enter the boot password.

It's on a Dell Precision M4600, if that matters.  Is there some kind of BIOS setting I can change to make it work?

UPDATE: Same behavior in both UEFI and BIOS boot settings.  If I hit F12 on boot, I can get into GRUB, but when I choose to boot Ubuntu from there, It goes to a black screen.  When I chose Recovery mode, it prompted me for my password and I was able to continue the boot from there, but that's not a real solution.

EDIT: Following the answers from [Purple screen on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66349/purple-screen-on-boot) had no effect: Hitting 'e' from the GRUB menu and changing 'quiet splash' to 'nomodeset'  - still blank purple screen.

EDIT: Completely unencrypted install works fine, with the caveat that reboots sometimes hang.  Unfortunately, full encryption is a requirement.  The fact that I can boot from recovery mode gives me hope, but I'm not nearly experienced enough to have a clue where to look.

FURTHER UPDATE: booting from a USB gets past the purple Ubuntu screen with the color changing dots, and then goes to a black screen with no disk activity. Left shift did NOT drop me into GRUB.  Booting from CD to re-install works, but what I really want is to just fix what's broken.

Comment: Nope, tried the solutions there to no effect.

Comment: Commented by @Mike: your laptop configured to boot from UEFI mode (secure boot) or BIOS mode (normal mode) This options can be found in bios setting

Comment: As I said above, I tried both settings, with the same results.

Comment: Don't give up! I do not really know the exact problem but here is a thought; have you tried downloading another Ubuntu iso or version and try to install with encryption? I have never had this problem with my Ubuntu installations however sometimes their may be disc errors with your install image that may cause your problems.

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired effect by putting boot passwords on the machine, so it's not worth spending more time diagnosing.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having a similar problem, can decrypt my drive at boot, but then a black screen and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you encrypted your home directory you should select ( require a password to log in and decrypt your home directory ) this option you can select while you are setting up Ubuntu  . try to setup Ubuntu without encrypt option if everything went well then your laptop configuration and hardware ok (you can use this command ecryptfs-setup-private to encrypt your home directory )

Comment: I have successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without any encryption.  I wanted the encrypted boot, not the encrypted home directory.  This is a requirement of the project that will be using this machine.

Comment: If you want to encrypt your boot you can do this with 'ecryptfs-setup-private'   but i just did a fresh  Ubuntu setup with encrypt option i used ubuntu 15.04  and every thing went well .

Comment: i changed bios sitting to bios mode (normal mode) and i start the setup   i used erase disk and and marked encyrpt the new ubuntu installtion  and used lvm with the new ubuntu installation i added my password for the security key , at the end i wrote my computer name and i use a password to log in to my system

Comment: Mike, I tried all that and it did not work.  That is why I am asking for help, to find out if anyone can explain what went wrong and how to fix it.